The homology of an infinite space.
I reached out to the point that the chain complex looks like this:
$$0 \to C_1 \xrightarrow{\partial_1} C_0 \xrightarrow{\partial_0} 0$$
And I think $\partial_0$ is just the zero map and $\partial_1$ is the projection on the endpoints of each unit interval (the delta complex structure I am using is $0$-simplex which is just a vertex for each integer in $\mathbb R$ and one simplex which is an edge for each interval $[a, a+1]$ with $a \in \mathbb Z.$). Now, the simplicial homology rule says $H_0$ is ker  $\partial_0$/ im  $\partial_1.$ I believe $C_0$ is just infinite direct sum of $\mathbb Z$ because the zeroth homology of a point is just $\mathbb Z$ and $C_1$ is also just infinite direct sum of $\mathbb Z$ because each interval is contractible and we have infinite number of them. The kernel of $\partial_0$ is the whole $C_0$ and so it is infinite direct sum of $\mathbb Z$ but the image of $\partial_1$ is what confuses me, is it infinite direct sum of $\mathbb Z$'s two times but then when I mod out by it what I will get then?
My guess was that the simplicial homology of the real line is just infinite direct sum of $\mathbb Z$  but now my justification for it seems to have a flaw.
Also what about the kernel of $\partial_1$? Is it just zero? I am just guessing, if so why? If not what is it then?
Any clarification will be greatly appreciated!

Let's keep calm. Computing with infinite triangulations is maybe a bit harder so if you're new to these computations, which I guess you are, I would recommend trying some compact examples like $S^1$ or the $\Delta$-structures on projective space, the Klein bottle etc. all the classics.
$C_0=\bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z$ where each canonical basis element $e_n$ represents the point $n\in\Bbb R$. $C_1=\bigoplus_{n\in\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z$ where each canonical basis element $e'_n$ represents the interval $[n, n+1]$. $\partial_1$ maps $e'_n\to e_{n+1}-e_n$. Your "guess" $\partial_0$ is zero is correct - it couldn't be anything else! There is only one map $C_0\to 0$, the zero map.
The kernel of $\partial_1$ consists of all generic elements $\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}a_ne'_n$, with all but finitely many $a_n$ are zero, such that $0=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}a_n(e_{n+1}-e_n)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}(a_{n-1}-a_n)e_n$. We realise $a_{n-1}=a_n$ for all $n$ is demanded. By induction, the sequence $(a_m)_{m\in\Bbb Z}$ is constant. But if all but finitely many $a_n$ are zero, that constant is zero! So the element $\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}a_ne'_n=0$; the kernel of $\partial_1$ is zero. That's what we'd hope, since $\Bbb R$ is contractible ..
Intuitively with the kernel of $\partial_1$ you're being asked for what the loops are. Walking along the intervals $[n, n+1]$ to form a loop I have no choice but to double back on myself, no loop is nontrivial. Now with the cokernel of $\partial_1$ you're being asked to identify path components. $\Bbb R$ is path connected so you should get $\Bbb Z$ as your answer (the free group on one path component!).
The image of $\partial_1$ is just the collection of all $\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}(a_{n-1}-a_n)e_n$, where $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb Z}$ is a sequence with all but finitely many terms zero. That means $\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}(a_{n-1}-a_n)=0$ makes sense; the series telescopes. Exercise: convince yourself, using this "all but finitely many" thing, that $\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}b_ne_n$ is in the image of $\partial_1$ iff. $\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}b_n=0$. Hint: try to build the sequence $a_n$ by induction, starting with the first $N$ such that $b_N\neq0$. Remember $b$ is zero all but finitely often.
Anyway, this is actually a general principle! You see this 'trace' map appear in reduced homology. That is, there is a map $C_0\to\Bbb Z$ given by this trace sum - it obviously is a surjective map - and the kernel is exactly the image of $\partial_1$ (well ok, in the case of homology of a path connected space), so it follows $C_0/\mathrm{im}\partial_1\cong\Bbb Z$.

I guess more precisely, I wanted to ask why $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} a_n e_{n+1} = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} a_{n - 1} e_{n}$?

Are you saying that $e_{n+1}$ should be equal $e_n$? Why is that?

@Emptymind No $e_n$ is not the same as $e_{n+1}$. This is a simple reindexing. Note the index on the $a_n$ changes accordingly to $a_{n-1}$.

Is not Coker $(\partial_1) = C_0/ im \partial_1 = C_0/  ker \partial_0 = 0$?

I did not get you why there is a map $C_0 \to \mathbb Z$? Also, are you saying that $H_0$ is not infinite direct sum of $\mathbb Z$ and it is just  $\mathbb Z$?

Why we want this sum "(That means $\sum_{n\in\Bbb Z}(a_{n-1}-a_n)=0$ makes sense; )" to make sense in the image of $\partial_1$?

in the first line in the paragraph before last, what did you mean by "the image of $\partial_1$ is just ......are" ?

in the image of $\partial_1,$ why we need the sum of $b_n$ to be zero and not just each $b_n$ to be zero as in the kernel?

@Emptymind To your first comment! Understandably, you have seen a sequence and assumed, as usual, that it is exact. But no, the whole point of homology is that the sequence might not be exact and in this way we detect interesting features; a "hole" in the space is somehow indicated by an inexactitude of the sequence. Specifically, $C_0/\mathrm{im}\partial_1=C_0/\ker\partial_0$ is wrong and assumes the sequence is exact at $C_0$ which it almost never is (!! only for the empty space).

@Emptymind To your second comment. $H_0$ is not some infinite direct sum no, it is just the free Abelian group on the path components. It is just $\Bbb Z$ here. The map $C_0\to\Bbb Z$ is exactly the map I describe; we take some finite sum of vertices $\sum_i b_ie_i$ and map it to $\sum_i b_i\in\Bbb Z$.

The "is.. are" thing was a typo, I've removed 'are'. And finally, your phrasing in the final comment is weird. It is not worthy of ""just"" to ask each $b_n$ to be zero, this is way stronger than assuming $\sum_n b_n=0$. Of course if all the $b_n$ are zero i.e. the element is the zero element then $\sum_n b_n=0$ as well... but you could have things like $[1]-[0]$. This is in the kernel of my map but it is definitely not zero! And it is also the boundary of the $1$-simplex associated to $[0,1]$.

I think I got your point, thank you very much!!

@Emptymind You're welcome!
